# React: trigger onChange on checkbox input when changing checked state programmatically?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a ref to an `<input type="checkbox"/>` element, and when I programmatically set `checked=false` on the element, the element's `onChange` callback does *not* get called.

I tried using `ref.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'))` and `ref.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'))` and neither caused the React `onChange` callback to get executed.

All the questions and answers I could find on StackOverflow about this have to do with `<input type="text"/>` elements, none dealing with changing the `checked` property programmatically on an `<input type="checkbox"/>` element and its `onChange` handler not being invoked.

Here's a CodePen that demonstrates the issue:

https://codepen.io/dossy/pen/QWKVNzZ/left/?editors=0011

You can check and uncheck the checkbox, and the `<div>Checked!</div>` will appear and disappear as expected.  However, clicking the `<button>Reset</button>` will uncheck the checkbox if it's checked, but since the `input`'s `onChange` handler isn't being executed, the `div` isn't being hidden as it should be.

...

**Yes, I *know* that I could do this as a [Controlled Component](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) but that's not the point: I have a use case where using refs is required so I must implement this as an [Uncontrolled Component](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html), and getting the `onChange` handler to execute when the DOM element changes is the problem I need to solve.**

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the working code. working link https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-wozniak-cc1sn?file=/src/Test.js:0-1753

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
export function Test() {
  const ref_input = useRef(null);
  const ref_text = useRef(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    ref_input.current.addEventListener("change", function (event) {
      alert(event.target.checked);
    });
  }, []);
  function triggerEvent(element, eventName) {
    var event = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
    event.initEvent(eventName, false, true);
    element.dispatchEvent(event);
  }

  return (
    <div className="h-screen flex bg-white text-gray-900 justify-center items-center">
      <div className="flex items-start w-64">
        <div className="flex items-center gap-4">
          <button
            className="inline-flex items-center px-4 py-2 border border-gray-500 rounded-md"
            onClick={() => {
              ref_input.current.checked = false;
              triggerEvent(ref_input.current, "change");
              //ref_input.dispatchEvent(new Event("input"));
              //ref_input.current.dispatchEvent(new Event("onChange"));
            }}
          >
            Reset
          </button>
          <div>Checkbox:</div>
          <input
            ref={ref_input}
            type="checkbox"
            className="h-4 w-4 border-gray-300 rounded"
            // onChange={(e) => {
            //   console.log("onChange called", e.target.checked);
            //   e.target.checked
            //     ? ref_text.current.classList.remove("hidden")
            //     : ref_text.current.classList.add("hidden");
            // }}
          />
          <div ref={ref_text} className="hidden">
            Checked!
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: I've got to go on record, that this is the most "un-react-like" react code ever. Manually dispatching DOM events, manually adding DOM listeners, it's really really bad.

Comment: if you see, requirement, the requestor wants to use the ref due to some unspecified reason. This one of the ways, we can achieve this. I understand this not the proper react design pattern  but the requestor has a different requirement,

Comment: I'm very experienced with React, and started out just as the requestor did - not understanding declarative code, the whole point of state and how to lift it up. This code won't help the requestor, only prolong their way of doing things incorrectly and not learning react.

Comment: I respect your experience with React. I am just trying to help with this unique requirement? Am I did anything wrong providing answer?

Comment: @Sam - Thanks, I was hoping to avoid `.addEventListener()` and finding some way of invoking the `input onChange` callback, but I suspect this may be the only way out.  The _only_ alternative I've found is instead of setting the `checked` property directly, using `.click()` on the `input` element, which DOES invoke the `onChange` callback on the `input` element, but I'm not sure what the other side-effects there could be when using `.click()`.

Comment: SO has always been this way - somebody asks how to accomplish Y because they've come to a place (through their own understanding) that, if they can figure out how to do Y, then they can solve their original problem, which is X. If you can understand what problem they're actually trying to solve (which is often not the one being asked) then you can help them way better. SO is supposed to help people - I stand by my original statement on this answer - it does not provide help in using react, because react simply isn't supposed to be done this way, despite the fact that you can make it work.

Comment: @dossy if you think, it helps please upvote or accept the answer, it can help others.

Comment: @Adam let SO decide if I did anything wrong providing an answer to this question.

Comment: @Sam - I'm going to leave this question open for a few days to see if someone can provide a solution where the `input` element keeps its `onChange` handler rather than using an event listener directly on the DOM element, but I suspect this is the only way.  I may end up going the `.click()` route, which will trigger the `input onChange` handler, but I wonder if that'll mess with analytics events logging click events ...

Comment: @Sam - you've got a memory leak in your code because you don't remove your listener when the component unmounts.

Comment: This code works as expected when the button is clicked but when I change the checkbox state from the console, the change is visible on the checkbox (checked/unchecked) but the "change" event isn't triggered so no alert is prompted.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to do things the "react way".

That means, instead of manipulating dom elements with imperative code (if you're using refs, you're using imperative code), do it declaratively with state/props:

```
function App() {
  const [checked,setChecked] = React.useState(false);
  return (
    <div className="h-screen flex bg-white text-gray-900 justify-center items-center">
      <div className="flex items-start w-64">
        <div className="flex items-center gap-4">
          <button
            className="inline-flex items-center px-4 py-2 border border-gray-500 rounded-md"
            onClick={() => setChecked(false)}
          >
            Reset
          </button>
          <div>Checkbox:</div>
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            checked={checked}
            onChange={() => setChecked(!checked)}
            className="h-4 w-4 border-gray-300 rounded"
          />
          <div className={checked ? '' : 'hidden'}>
            Checked!
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Here's a link to the updated pen: https://codepen.io/zuze-lab/pen/QWKVEbY?editors=0011

EDIT: I want to be really clear, ref's aren't bad, not at all. Lots of react libraries expose refs because imperative code makes sense for those libraries APIs. When using refs to add event listeners, or imperatively manipulate elements, you're doing things wrong and you need to back up.

Comment: Thanks, but I already said I cannot use [Controlled Components](https://itnext.io/controlled-vs-uncontrolled-components-in-react-5cd13b2075f9) in this particular case.

Comment: There's other ways to do it without a controlled component - I can help you out further if you explain the restriction on why you can't use them.

Comment: Suppose, instead of just showing/hiding a simple `div`, I am manipulating the DOM state of an element that cannot be created/destroyed, and must instead have its DOM state manipulated in the `input` element's `onChange` handler, which is an anonymous arrow function and cannot be invoked directly in JS.  Why will React not invoke the `onChange` handler when the underlying `input` DOM element state changes?  Can I get React to actually define the `onchange` property on the DOM element?

Comment: @dossy - forget about DOM elements. Stop thinking about them. How things are done in vanillajs is very different than react and it will take some time to get your head around it (as it did me - I was doing things exactly as you were). But that doesn't mean you should fall back to your vanillajs comfort-zone because you don't know how to "do" react yet. You'll get there, but don't ignore good answers because you don't understand them.

Comment: @dossy - to answer your question - you store your state in react (https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) instead of in the DOM so the DOM is not your source of truth, your declaractive code is.

Comment: Suppose you are embedding an `iframe`, what then?  Sometimes, you have elements where the DOM must be your source of truth.  Thanks for your suggestion, though!

Comment: @dossy - Only in the rarest of cases (which most people will never encounter) is the DOM supposed to be your source of truth when using react. You haven't encountered one here. This is your fundamental misunderstanding - bring your "state" into your react code and just let the DOM "display" the state that you have encoded, and have your code "REACT" to changes (onChange, onClick, etc)